# SharpPcap SendQueue failed due to casting failed

Tags: c#

i try to send packets from pcap file (libpcap) using SharpPcap and using the example from SharpPcap:

http://sourceforge.net/p/sharppcap/code/ci/SharpPcap_4_1_0/tree/Examples/Example10.SendQueue/Example10.SendQueues.cs

now my problem is in line 124: `var winPcapDevice = device as WinPcapDevice;`

the `device` is my networl card adapter and after choosing this device it inst null but after the command `var winPcapDevice = device as WinPcapDevice;` the variable `winPcapDevice` is null probably because  the type is not expected one and therefore the SendQueue failed to transmit.
this example is taken from the project page, maybe someone familiar with this project and can tell me how to solve it ?

Comment: try replacing your code with this: var winPcapDevice = (WinPcapDevice)device; - This will force your code to break due to the cast failure, instead of failing silently (which is what the "as" keyword does). You should be able to use the exception to work out what the issue might be due to.

Comment: Also, what type is "device" bound to?

Comment: Error: Unable to cast object of type 'SharpPcap.LibPcap.LibPcapLiveDevice' to ty
pe 'SharpPcap.WinPcap.WinPcapDevice'. device it the network card that the packets need to be send

Comment: The cast is the wrong way round. You can cast a WinPcap device to a LibPcap device, but not vice-versa. can "device" be instantiated as a WinPcap device? or, are there any methods on device which returns it's equivalent WinPcap device? (take a look though the SharpPcap documentation)

Comment: the Send Queue method refer only for WinPcapDevice.